# Why doesn't the stripe customer token gets saved in my database?

Tags: javascript, ruby, database, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm currently taking the upskill tutorial "The Essential Web Developer Course"(currently on lesson 162) where i try to connect Stripe with a payment for a premium membership. This tutorial is working with older versions of the gems and libraries, etc., thats why I'm telling you that.

The problem is that after Stripe sends me back a costumer token. It won't get stored in my db and it won't sign in to the membership. Instead my submit button will stay disabled and shows the string "Processing".

The dev-console shows the: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined" message.

What do I need to change?  Has it sth. to do with my save_with_subscription method?

```
  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
  def save_with_subscription
   if valid?
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: plan_id, card: stripe_card_token)
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
   end
```

The js file for it:

```
/* global $, Stripe */
//Document ready.
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  var theForm = $('#pro_form');
  var submitBtn = $('#form-signup-btn');
  //Set Stripe public key.
  Stripe.setPublishableKey( $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content') );
  //When user clicks form submit btn,
  submitBtn.click(function(event){
    //prevent default submission behavior.
    event.preventDefault();
    submitBtn.val("Processing").prop('disabled', true);
    //Collect the credit card fields.
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();
    //Use Stripe JS library to check for card errors.
    var error = false;
    //Validate card number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The credit card number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate CVC number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The CVC number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate expiration date.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The expiration date appears to be invalid');
    }
    if (error) {
      //If there are card errors, don't send to Stripe.
      submitBtn.prop('disabled', false).val("Sign Up");
    } else {
      //Send the card info to Stripe.
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  });
  //Stripe will return a card token.
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    //Get the token from the response.
    var token = response.id;
    //Inject the card token in a hidden field.
    theForm.append( $('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]">').val(token) );
    //Submit form to our Rails app.
    theForm.get(0).submit();
  }
});
```

All of my code can be found at https://github.com/JakkSwords/upskill_saas_tutorial/tree/user_memberships

Comment: Can you please confirm that stripe_card_token is getting set?  Same for email and plan_id?

Comment: From that error (and your [code](https://github.com/JakkSwords/upskill_saas_tutorial/blob/user_memberships/app/assets/javascripts/users.js#L56)) looks like the submit function is called not on the submit button, or the form itself in your javascript. Can you check that you use the form lookup there correctly?

Comment: button  type="submit" id="form-signup-button"

Comment: Thats how the button is declared in views/devise/registrations/_pro_form.html.erb : <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn btn-success', id: 'form-signup-btn' %>